# How to know the state of a window service using command prompt

Tags: java, batch-file, service, command-prompt

I an using a batch file processing some 10 commands. At a certain level, I want to proceed only if my specific Window Service is in a "running" state. How do I get to know the state of a service using `cmd` command? And how do I store the result of a command in a variable in a batch file or execute a command in a batch file depending on result of another command?

Comment: For checking services there is the `sc` command (and its sub-commands `query`/`queryex`) -- type `sc /?` on command prompt to find out more; to get the result of a command into a variable, use `for /F` -- type `for /?` for help...

Answer (score 0):

Look inside this script http://pastebin.com/dyG9XYhC , we are using it for restarting and stopping services.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
sc query Dhcp | findstr /i "STATE"
pause
```

You can use the following command to see if a service is running or not:

```
sc query ServiceName | findstr /i "STATE"
```

When I run it for **DHCP service** , I get:

```
STATE                       : 4 RUNNING
```

If it was stopped, I would get:

```
STATE                       : 1 STOPPED
```

**Note :** The service name should be the **service name**, not the **display name**.

***EDIT on 05/05/2016 @16:20***

This an example for checking the state of some Services with `FOR` command :

```
@echo off
Title Checking the state of some Services
set ServiceName=MozillaMaintenance MDM AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc Winmgmt wuauserv ^
^ ALG AIPS Themes gupdate gupdatem msiserver AppInfo AppMgmt PlugPlay Power bthserv ^
^ NetLogon SamSs ProtectedStorage W32Time pla MpsSvc UxSms TabletInputService

For %%a in (%ServiceName%) do (
    echo Service %%a & sc query %%a | findstr /i "STATE"
)
pause
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i need to restore the service state in another variable for further use.